# is it possible to use supports statement in if statement in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

what I'm trying to do is I want to write into a file if the service is running as RUNNING and if not, as NOT RUNNING.

```
service 'McAfeeFramework' do
puts 'true'
only_if{ supports :status =>true}

File.write('c:\chef-repo\n1.txt','running')
puts 'false'
only_if{ supports :status =>false}
File.write('c:\chef-repo\n1.txt','not running')
end
```

Comment: Your taking it backward,`supports` property is what **you** define, not something giving the status of the service. Best bet would be a `powershell_script` resource to write the service status into a file (but why would you want to do that ?)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? This is very much counter to how Chef works best.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the [service resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html) wrong.

A [service resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html) can be used to manage a service in the system, like enabling, disabling, starting or stopping it. The [guards](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) you are using (only_if, not_if) are meant to trigger the resource action only under certain circumstances. For example, only start a service if another one is running.

For the task you want to achieve here, you should use a [powershell_script resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_powershell_script.html), where you can write some real code to be executed in the provisioned node on each chef-client run, that will write the file.

=edit=

As coderanger stated, it *is* possible also to use a `file` resource for this, although you must create the logic in ruby to add content to it rather than PS.

Comment: You could definitely use a `file` resource for this, would just mean writing the logic in Ruby rather than PS.