# what is the right way to use if statement in chef?

Tags: if-statement, chef-infra

here the else part is not working I'm unable to figure out why , how do I execute this code successfully?

```
service 'McAfeeFramework' do
if{ supports :status =>true}
File.write('c:\chef-repo\n1.txt','running')
else
File.write('c:\chef-repo\n1.txt','not running')
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to use supports statement in if statement in chef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482182/is-it-possible-to-use-supports-statement-in-if-statement-in-chef)

Comment: Please along with reading the Chef tutorial at https://learn.chef.io, take some time to read [tour] and [ask]. Asking the same thing again and again is not welcome on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in your last question, what you have there is literally not related to Chef code. Please start with the https://learn.chef.io tutorials to learn the basics of writing Chef recipe code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to check if given process is running with chef. You need to replace procname with your process name. However this is example for Linux if you need Windows you need to change only_if statement to something like `sc query | find "RUNNING`

```
file 'running process' do
  path '/tmp/running_process'
  content 'services is running'
  only_if 'pgrep procname && echo 0'
  action :create
end

file 'stoped process' do
  path '/tmp/stoped_process'
  content 'services is not running'
  only_if 'pgrep procname || echo 1'
  action :create
end
```